# JQuery shared functions for multiple .load events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the JQuery .load function to pull some paragraphs from 3 separate URLs into 3 separate divs on my main page. Then, I want to use JQuery to add functions to each of the 3 divs on the main page.

Here's a (very) simplified version of what I have now:

Page 1 :

```
<div class="mycontent">
<P> test </p>
</div>
```

Page 2:

```
<div class="mycontent">
<p> test </p>
</div>
```

Page 3:

```
<div class="mycontent">
<p> test </p>
</div>
```

Main page markup:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Main page JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".div1").load("myurlA.aspx .mycontent p", function(){
$(".div1 p").wrapAll("<div class='x'></div>");
});

$(".div2").load("myurlB.aspx .mycontent p", function(){
$(".div2 p").wrapAll("<div class='x'></div>");
});

$(".div3").load("myurlC.aspx .mycontent p", function(){
$(".div3 p").wrapAll("<div class='x'></div>");
});

});
```

This works...but I'd like to use a single .wrapAll to wrap all paragraphs in all 3 divs. My actual main page has many more methods within in each .load function, and it just doesn't seem ideal to repeat the same methods. I've tried triggering my methods after the .load event, but I can't get them to work unless they're within the .load function.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code below is more dynamic, plus it wraps each div when its script is loaded.

```js
$(".div-link").each(function() {
  var current = $(this);
  var link = current.data("link");
  
  current.load(link + " .mycontent p", function() {
    $(this).children("p").wrapAll("<div class='x'></div>");
    console.log('loaded')
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-link" data-link="myurlA.aspx"></div>
<div class="div-link" data-link="myurlB.aspx"></div>
<div class="div-link" data-link="myurlC.aspx"></div>
```

Comment: I ended up using something a tad less complex. thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.when(
    $(".div1").load("myurlA.aspx .mycontent p")
    $(".div2").load("myurlB.aspx .mycontent p")
    $(".div3").load("myurlC.aspx .mycontent p")
  ).then(function() {
    $("div p").wrap("<div class='x'></div>")
  });
});
```

Comment: this will only wrap them when all the scripts are loaded, not on each.

Comment: This seems like it would be a great solution, yet I could not get it to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here's what ended up working for me:

```
$(".div1").load("myurlA.aspx .mycontent p", myFunction);
$(".div2").load("myurlB.aspx .mycontent p", myFunction);
$(".div3").load("myurlC.aspx .mycontent p", myFunction);

function myFunction(){

//shared methods & events//

};
```